# Which word is more appropriate to express "How it works"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Context Description:

I'm a programmer. One day I find an interesting software IPFinder published by Fred, but I can't understand how it works. So, I want to write an email to ask Fred.

> - A. What's the *mechanism* of IPFinder?
> - B. What's the *principle* of IPFinder?

Which is more proper in such a context, mechanism or principle?

Comment: I agree with @ruakh (but am no programmer): what's wrong with asking *How does this work*?

Answer (score 3):

Both questions are valid, but they mean slightly different things. This is how I would interpret them:

> What's the mechanism of IPFinder? = How does IPFinder perform its task(s)?
>
> What's the principle of IPFinder? = What is the concept that underpins the way IPFinder is written?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either of those sentences is very clear. The way that something works can definitely be a *mechanism* or a *principle*, but each of those words has a variety of meanings, and "What's the mechanism/principle of IPFinder?" just doesn't give enough context to identify the exact meaning that is meant.

I think you're better off just asking:

> How does IPFinder work?

or, to make clear that you're interested in technical details rather than end-user documentation, you might write something like:

> How does IPFinder work under the hood?